# Filtering on foreignkey django

Tags: django, django-models, filter, django-queryset

I have two models:

```
class Recipe(models.Model):
   title = models.CharField()
   ....
class Ingredient(models.Model):
   recipe = models.Foreignkey(Recipe, related_name='recipe_ingredients')
   name = models.CharField()
   ...
```

So what I want to do is filter out recipes by a given ingredient, I managed to do that this way:
view.py

```
class SearchResultListViewIngredient(ListView):
   model = Recipe
   paginate_by = 25
   template_name = 'recipes/search_ingredient.html'

   def get_queryset(self):
       """
       Filter out recipes by given ingredient
       """

       ingredient = self.request.GET.get('ingredient')
       object_list = []
       if ingredient:
          i = Ingredient.objects.filter(name__icontains=ingredient)
          object_list = [r.recipe for r in i]

       return object_list
```

The problem with this is that it returns duplicate objects if their are more then one ingredients with the same name.
So for example, a recipe that has as ingredient eggs and also eggplant. This object will appear twice after filtering. Is there a beter way of doing this filter?

Thanks in advance.

Edit:
I know I could wrap the object_list in a set() but that does not feel right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use distinct() to get distinct objects.

`recipes = Recipe.objects.filter(recipe_ingredients__name__icontains=ingredient).distinct()`